# merge multiple files based on column and print nth column R

Tags: r, join, merge

I have 3 files. I need to take 1st file and for each row, need to match the first column in file 2. Then take the corresponding Aliases from file2 and match it with file3 (description or Aliases column) then print the OMIM Ids.

```
File1:

**Symbol**
MCL1
ABCB1
BAX
IKZF1
WWOX
BCL2L1
BCL2L11
CCND1
TNFSF10

File2:

**Symbol2   Aliases**
MCL1    MCL1, BCL2 family apoptosis regulator
ABCB1   ATP binding cassette subfamily B member 1
WWOX    WW domain containing oxidoreductase
BCL2L1  RB transcriptional corepressor 1
BOK peroxisome proliferator activated receptor gamma
RHOA    ras homolog family member A
ABCC1   C-X-C motif chemokine ligand 12
PARP1   poly(ADP-ribose) polymerase 1
BAK1    BRCA1, DNA repair associated

file3:
**description   OMIM    Aliases**
MCL1, BCL2 family apoptosis regulator   159552  G protein subunit alpha 12
ATP binding cassette subfamily B member 1   171050  matrix metallopeptidase 9
BCL2 associated X, apoptosis regulator  600040  cadherin 1
IKAROS family zinc finger 1 603023  Janus kinase 2
WW domain containing oxidoreductase 605131  ataxin 3
BCL2 like 1 600039  RB transcriptional corepressor 1
BCL2 like 11    603827  transferrin receptor
cyclin D1   168461  C-C motif chemokine ligand 2
TNF superfamily member 10   603598  prostaglandin-endoperoxide synthase 2

Expected result:
**Symbol    Symbol1 description/Aliases OMIM**
MCL1    MCL1    MCL1, BCL2 family apoptosis regulator   159552
ABCB1   ABCB1   ATP binding cassette subfamily B member 1   171050
BAX         
IKZF1           
WWOX    WWOX    WW domain containing oxidoreductase 605131
BCL2L1  BCL2L1  RB transcriptional corepressor 1    600039
BCL2L11         
CCND1           
TNFSF10
```

I used merge and inner_join but not as expected. Any help?

Comment: Can you share your code so that the issue can be identified

Comment: I used `file1_2=merge(x = file1, y = file2, by = c("Symbol","Symbol2"), all=TRUE)` then `output = merge(x=file1_2, y=file3)`. But I want to match in either description/Aliases and append the corresponding OMIM column.

Comment: Check my answer below. Seems like there is an error in your merge function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is to rename relevant columns by which you'd like to merge, and then use `purrr::reduce` with `dplyr::left_join` (or in base R `Reduce` with `merge`)

```
names(df2) <- c("Symbol", "Description/Aliases")
names(df3) <- c("Description/Aliases", "OMIM", "Aliases")

purrr::reduce(list(df1, df2, df3), dplyr::left_join) %>% dplyr::select(-Aliases)
#   Symbol                       Description/Aliases   OMIM
#1    MCL1     MCL1, BCL2 family apoptosis regulator 159552
#2   ABCB1 ATP binding cassette subfamily B member 1 171050
#3     BAX                                      <NA>     NA
#4   IKZF1                                      <NA>     NA
#5    WWOX       WW domain containing oxidoreductase 605131
#6  BCL2L1          RB transcriptional corepressor 1     NA
#7 BCL2L11                                      <NA>     NA
#8   CCND1                                      <NA>     NA
#9 TNFSF10                                      <NA>     NA
```

Or in base R

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.x = T), list(df1, df2, df3))
```

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "Symbol
MCL1
ABCB1
BAX
IKZF1
WWOX
BCL2L1
BCL2L11
CCND1
TNFSF10", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text =
    "Symbol2   Aliases
MCL1    'MCL1, BCL2 family apoptosis regulator'
ABCB1   'ATP binding cassette subfamily B member 1'
WWOX    'WW domain containing oxidoreductase'
BCL2L1  'RB transcriptional corepressor 1'
BOK 'peroxisome proliferator activated receptor gamma'
RHOA    'ras homolog family member A'
ABCC1   'C-X-C motif chemokine ligand 12'
PARP1   'poly(ADP-ribose) polymerase 1'
BAK1    'BRCA1, DNA repair associated'", header = T)

df3 <- read.table(text =
    "description   OMIM    Aliases
'MCL1, BCL2 family apoptosis regulator'   159552  'G protein subunit alpha 12'
'ATP binding cassette subfamily B member 1'   171050  'matrix metallopeptidase 9'
'BCL2 associated X, apoptosis regulator'  600040  'cadherin 1'
'IKAROS family zinc finger 1' 603023  'Janus kinase 2'
'WW domain containing oxidoreductase' 605131  'ataxin 3'
'BCL2 like 1' 600039  'RB transcriptional corepressor 1'
'BCL2 like 11'    603827  'transferrin receptor'
'cyclin D1'   168461  'C-C motif chemokine ligand 2'
'TNF superfamily member 10'   603598  'prostaglandin-endoperoxide synthase 2'", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your `merge` statement. The syntax is `merge(x, y, by.x, by.y, all)`. So your code would be something like:

```
df1 <- merge(file_1, file_2, by.x = "Symbol", by.y = "Symbol2", all.x = TRUE)
df2 <- merge(df1, file_3, by.x = "Aliases", by.y = "description", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I retain description/Aliases from file2 (as shown in expected result)

Comment: I think df2 should have all the columns from all 3 files. It may have changed names though (like Aliases.x)

Comment: I used your code and here is my output file colnames :  `Aliases Symbol   OMIM                  Aliases.y` , what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That is the "Aliases" column in your resulting dataset. The "Aliases.y" is your Aliases column from file_3